# Install SQlite for Ionic4 Vue

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm trying to add SQlite to my ionic4 project, but get installation errors.

My NPM install was this:

```
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
    npm install @ionic-native/sqlite

    //ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage ==> this one makes error
```

In main.js, I tried each of the following:

```
    import SQLite from 'ionic-native';
    import {SQLite} from 'ionic-native';
    import SQLite from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
    import {SQLite} from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
    import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

Here are the errors: a) npm warning, b) console error, and c) Chrome inspector for main.js
[image: ionic native sqlite webpack is not constructor]

And here's the code from main.js (last line is where everything fails).

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App },
      render : (h) => h(App),
      mounted() {

        this.storage = new SQLite();
```

*** I marked this question as answered, but there appears to be no answer yet. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Did you read the usage page? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite#usage

Comment: The usage page is for Angular (right?).  Everything I try from this page fails to compile.

Comment: No, that's a universal page - notice how it doesn't have any framework-specific code

Comment: Sorry, am I mistaken that ngx is an Angular acronym?  Import from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ionic/vue is still in beta and the team is [working on](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-the-ionic-vue-beta/) integrating it with the Vue CLI. They are also using Capacitor, not Cordova, as the official native bridge for this project. As such it is recommended to use Capacitor if at all possible. Should you go that route, their [storage API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage) is available in lieu of SQLite.

If you would like to persist with your Cordova project, the Ionic Storage abstraction won't be available so you would have to bypass Ionic altogether.

Install the [plugin](https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage) using the Cordova CLI (`@ionic-native/sqlite` is not required):

`cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

Use the plugin directly e.g.

`const db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({...})`

`db.executeSql('INSERT...', [...values], callbackFn, errorFn)`

Comment: The ngx import doesn't work.  However, I am now going to attempt the Capacitor/storage API and see how far I get.  Thanks!

Comment: @JenniferMichelle I realise you can't use the Ionic storage API at all with Ionic 4 and Cordova. So it's either Capacitor or use the Cordova plugin directly. Answer updated.

Comment: After struggling all day to get Capacitor to do anything at all, could you advise whether I can use cordova within an Ionic4 Vue project?  

I think it has to be an 'ionic project' instead of a 'Cordova project' order for my devApp to work.  "cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage" makes error (as do 
all attempts beginning with 'cordova'.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle how did you set up your project? Could you post a link to the repo?

Comment: Here's the page I was writing for my team -- it's taken me a month to get this far in the installation.  Writing the app is easy by comparison & I have managed to do everything except tap into native OS functions like storage, camera, etc.  I'm using the devApp.  https://btn.ninja/page.ionvuesetup.php

Comment: Have you followed Paul Halliday's tutorial which is referenced by the official Ionic docs? The setup you have outlined looks quite non-standard for an Ionic app (e.g. the deps are global instead of local). I would think of an @ionic/vue app more like a Vue app that uses Ionic components than an Ionic app that uses the Vue framework. https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-ionic/

Comment: I have done all his tutorials, and I think devApp only worked if it was an ionic project.  Since I don't have a Mac for xcode, and the new Ionic Studio seems to be written for Angular, I need the devApp to work.  However, I'll try this tutorial again now, just to be sure.  I have found no way possible to make Ionic Vue native functions work in devApp & therefore no way to see them work at all.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle it seems your real problem is getting devapp to work with Ionic/Vue. Perhaps a question targeted to that would raise more interest? In the meantime, I'll have a think.

Comment: devApp is working with Ionic Vue for everything except native functions.  Today I'm trying to get any Cordova function working.  Thanks for your help on this.   :)

Comment: @JenniferMichelle this author got devapp working with Ionic, Vue and Cordova FYI: https://medium.com/@dlodeprojuicer/using-cordova-in-an-ionic-vue-app-the-almost-complete-guide-d6423c248257